# vue.js basic show/hide inside of a method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am brand new to vuejs. Impressive framework so I am learning how to re-do all the other things I would normally do with jquery with vue.js.  My main issue I am facing is that within a method, I am trying to show or hide a div based no whether a condition is met. It is not working accurately. It does show, but never hides. The admin div is only supposed to be present if the two users are logged in.

```html
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tachyons/css/tachyons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .panel-footer {

            height: 40px !important;
        }

        body {
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        .blue {
            color: #0079C2;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">hello world
    </div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.0.3/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data: {
                items: [],
                Title: ""
            },
            created: function() {
                this.getCurrentUser();
            },
            methods: {
                getCurrentUser: function() {
                    var root = 'https://example.com';
                    var headers = {
                        accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"

                    }
                    var vm = this;
                    var __REQUESTDIGEST = '';
                    $.ajax({
                        url: root + "_api/web/currentuser",
                        type: 'Get',
                        headers: headers,
                        success: function(data) {

                            vm.Title = data.d.Title;
                            console.log(vm.Title)
                            if (vm.Title == "Marks, Wendy" || "Adams, Todd") {
                                document.getElementById("admin").style.display = "block";
                            }else
                            
                            {
                             document.getElementById("admin").style.display = "none";

                            }


                        }

                    })

                },

             
            }
        })

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Add a field show : true in your data. Then use <div v-if="show"></div>... update show variable to true false whenever you want to show or hide that <div>

Comment: would I use vm.Title=="Orrin, Stephen"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Vue` lets you do [`conditional rendering`](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/conditional.html). You don't need to do like

```
 document.getElementById("admin").style.display = "block";
```

Or anything like that.

just use `v-if` binding of `vuejs`. This will do that for you. Like

```
 <div id="admin" v-if="Title ==X"></div>
```

Another option for conditionally displaying an element is the `v-show` directive. The usage is largely the same:

```
<div id="admin" v-show="Title ==X"></div>
```

Comment: would I use vm.Title=="Orrin, Stephen"